# Can I do this with conditionals

Tags: conditionals, solspace, supersearch

Hi I'm looking for a way to repeat this process to build a title with conditionals

In the php version of my site I can use the following

```
if (!empty($PostKeyword)) {
    $PostTitle = $PostKeyword." Jobs";
    if (!empty($PostLoc)) {
        $PostTitle = $PostKeyword." Jobs in ". $PostLoc;
    }
} elseif (!empty($PostCategory)) {
    $PostTitle = $PostCategory." Jobs";
    if (!empty($PostLoc)) {
        $PostTitle = $PostCategory." Jobs in ". $PostLoc;
    }
} else {
    $PostTitle = "Jobs In ". $PostLoc;
}
```

I was hoping this could do the same with this in EE but it just throws errors

```
{if {super_search_keywords} !=""}

    <h1>{super_search_keywords} Jobs</h1>

{if:elseif super_search_category_name !=""}

    {if {super_search_job_location} !=""}
        <h1>{super_search_category_name} Jobs In {super_search_job_location}</h1>
    {/if}

    <h1>{super_search_category_name} Jobs</h1>

{if:else}

    <h1>Jobs In {super_search_job_location}</h1>

{/if}
```

Sorry for the look I cant find a way to format this nicely

Comment: Which errors? Please, add them to your question.

Comment: If I searched with a category and location the page wouldn't load and I'd get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_NOT_EQUAL in /home/jobsonli/public_html/addon/jobsarena.co.uk/jobsysonline/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code on line 5

Answer (score 3):

The error happens because, sometimes, the conditionals brakes after a stage of parsing. Example:

```
{if {x} != ""}
```

If, `x` is empty, the conditional will be turned into:

```
{if != ""}
```

Which doesn't make sense.

So, you can use:

```
{if "{x}" != ""}
```

Or the what the [Template Class calls "short conditionals"](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#conditional-variables):

```
{if x}
```

I suggest you to try:

```
{if "{super_search_keywords}" !=""}

    <h1>{super_search_keywords} Jobs</h1>

{if:elseif "{super_search_category_name}" !=""}

    {if "{super_search_job_location}" !=""}
        <h1>{super_search_category_name} Jobs In {super_search_job_location}</h1>
    {/if}

    <h1>{super_search_category_name} Jobs</h1>

{if:else}

    <h1>Jobs In {super_search_job_location}</h1>

{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend using the excellent [IfElse plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse) to reduce load with advanced conditionals. To do this wrap your entire conditional in these tags:

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}    
  code goes here
{/exp:ifelse}
```

Now onwards, please post the errors you are seeing as that will help us help you. Second, I would start off by simplifying your entire conditional to a single conditional and checking if that works. If it does then add the next part and repeat until you have found the error or have the entire thing working.

You might also try putting supersearch variables inside quotes:

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}    
    {if '{super_search_keywords}' !=""}

        <h1>{super_search_keywords} Jobs</h1>

     {/if}

    {if '{super_search_category_name}' !=""}

        {if '{super_search_job_location}' !=""}
            <h1>{super_search_category_name} Jobs In {super_search_job_location}</h1>
        {/if}

        <h1>{super_search_category_name} Jobs</h1>

    {if:else}

        <h1>Jobs In {super_search_job_location}</h1>

    {/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

Comment: Hi Sean thanks for taking the time to look at this I installed the suggested plugin tried just a simple[code] {exp:ifelse parse="inward"}    
    {if {super_search_keywords} !=""}
        <h1>{super_search_keywords} Jobs ifelse</h1>
     {/if} 
{/exp:ifelse}[/code] Yet I get no title when the keyword isn't empty so I'm not sure if I can do this with super search

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Robson Sobral you set me on the right track the following fixes the conditionals

```
{if "{super_search_keywords}" !=""}
    <h1>{super_search_keywords} Jobs {if "{super_search_job_location}" !=""}
         In {super_search_job_location}
    {/if}</h1>

{if:elseif "{super_search_category}" !=""}
 <h1>{super_search_category} Jobs {if "{super_search_job_location}" !=""}
         In {super_search_job_location}
    {/if}</h1>


{if:else}
    <h1>Jobs In {super_search_job_location}</h1>
{/if}
```

I have one more thing which maybe should ask in a new question the {super_search_category} can only pull back the category ID is there anyway to convert this id to the name